# Command line perl print lines between patterns only for a last match

Tags: perl, command-line

I am looking for a perl one liner command to get the lines with pattern with non greedy match.
PATTERN1 SOME INFO

TEXT1

TEXT2

TEXT3 PATTERN2 SOME INFO

PATTERN1 SOME INFO

TEXT4

TEXT5

TEXT6 PATTERN3 SOME INFO

I know the following code
perl -ne 'print if (/PATTERN1/../PATTERN3/)' is a greedy match and prints everthing.

What I want is to print the following output
*PATTERN1 SOME INFO
TEXT4
TEXT5
TEXT6 PATTERN3 SOME INFO*

Note this is extremely large file and can't put the whole file into a string.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really "restart" the flip-flop operator as it's too simplistic. It stops looking for the start condition until it meets the end condition. Additionally, you are running that code once per line, so by the time you get to the second `PATTERN1`, the preceding lines have already been printed to the output. This means to do what you want you need to do two things: expand the algorithm so you can customize it, and process the whole input before printing output (this doesn't necessarily mean reading it all into one string, but you do have to buffer the part you're looking at until you know whether to print it).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($in_section, @buffer);
while (my $line = readline) {
  $in_section = 1, undef @buffer if $line =~ m/PATTERN1/;
  push @buffer, $line if $in_section;
  $in_section = 0, print @buffer if $line =~ m/PATTERN3/;
}
```

As a oneliner it could look like:

```
perl -nE 'our ($in, @buf); $in = 1, undef @buf if /PATTERN1/;
  push @buf, $_ if $in; $in = 0, print @buf if /PATTERN3/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to print lines delimited by the shortest span of `PATTERN1` and `PATTERN3`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $flag = 0;
my @lines;
while (<<>>) {
    if ( /PATTERN1/ ) {
        $flag = 1;
        @lines = ();
    }
    push @lines, $_ if $flag;
    if ( /PATTERN3/ ) {
        $flag = 0;
        print join "", @lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hakon for the code snippet. It works. Looks we can't do with out buffering.